# On the convergence of a series$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n W(n)}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

How to show convergence of  $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n W(n)}$$ where $W(n)$ denotes the product of distinct primes dividing n.

Comment: Hint.  Write $n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\dots p_k^{e_k}$.  We have that $n W(n)$ will have the same primes as $n$ does in its prime factorization, but all the $e_i$ will be at least two.  Does this tell you anything?

Comment: @Mark But the set is still a lot bigger than the set of squares.

Comment: to complete what Jack D'Aurizio said : $\frac{1}{n W(n)}$ is multiplicative, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n W(n)} = \prod_p (1+ \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{p^k W(p^k)}) = \prod_p (1+ \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{p^{k+1}}) = \prod_p (1+ \frac{1}{p(p-1)})$ at least formally, and since everything is non-negative the (absolute) convergence of the RHS proves the (absolute) convergence of the LHS

Comment: @user1952009: thanks for the addendum. I edited my answer since I noticed that the given sum (quite surprisingly) has a nice closed form, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I had the same surprise in an other discussion about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{\phi(n) n} = \prod_p 1-\frac{1}{p (p-1)}$

Comment: We like to see questions that show some form of *context*.  This can take the form of showing your work, explaining how you came across the problem, or detailed explanation of what is confusing you.  This helps us help you better.

Answer (score 4):

If we consider some finite subset $E$ of the prime numbers and restrict the given series to the natural numbers divided by each prime in $E$ (let we call this subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as $E'$), we get

$$ \sum_{n\in E'}\frac{1}{n W(n)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{p\in E}p}\sum_{n\in E'}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{\left(\prod_{p\in E}p\right)^2}\prod_{p\in E}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}}=\prod_{p\in E}\frac{1}{p(p-1)} $$
hence the sum restricted to the integers that are divided by *some* prime in $E$ equals $\prod_{p\in E}\left(1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)$, and by taking the limit on both sides as "$E$ tends to the set of all primes", which is valid because everything is nonnegative:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n W(n)}=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right) $$
and the last infinite product is convergent since $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$ is convergent, but bounded below by
$$ \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}=\zeta(2).$$
On the other hand, we may also compute it exactly:
$$ \prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^3}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}}=1.94359643682\ldots $$

Comment: Thanks to Greg Martin, too, for the improvement.

Comment: Anyway, I restored the RHS of the first identity since it was correct: at the beginning, I am considering that set of integers that are divided by *each* prime in $E$.

Comment: Wow what a nice form. This is totally unbelievable for me that it could have such a nice form in form of zeta function.